# Using Pycharm virtualenv with preexisting files

Tags: python, pycharm, virtualenv

I was sent a bunch of Python files that have various custom dependencies inside nested folders. I used to run the main file from Terminal by first navigating to the main folder, then running `python main.py`. This worked until I needed to update some modules and ran into permissions problems.

So I downloaded Pycharm and I'm trying to use a virtualenv. I'm stuck though: do I create a new Pycharm project?

Under the project interpreter, I made a new virtualenv with no modules, but when I do `pip list` in the command window that's below, it lists all my modules.

How can I "import" my existing Python files, put them in a clean virtualenv, and install the modules I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PyCharm, do File -> Open and point at the directory. It will turn that directory into a "project" (meaning, it will create a .idea subdirectory). Depending on how you named your virtualenv, it will likely detect the virtualenv and assign it the project's interpreter.